# Can't ping ubuntu server after reboot. Where to look for possible problems?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ping

After restarting my Ubuntu Server I can't ping it. My hosting (Herzner) allows to boot server with rescue system, so I can access file system and try to fix it.

The questions is, **where to look for problems?**

I checked my boot.log and everything seems to look fine:

```
cat boot.log 
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting bluetooth daemon                                             [ OK ]
 * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server                                 [ OK ]
 * Stopping OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting vsftpd daemon                                                [fail]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting modem connection manager                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Starting vsftpd daemon                                                [fail]
 * Stopping configure virtual network devices                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting network connection manager                                   [ OK ]
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                                            [ OK ] 
 * Loading cpufreq kernel modules...                                     [ OK ] 
 * CPU0...                                                               [ OK ]  * CPUFreq Utilities: Setting ondemand CPUFreq governor...       
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation                            [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon                 [ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting LightDM Display Manager                                      [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon                              [ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon                             [ OK ]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon                               [ OK ]
```

Comment: Is `ifconfig` reports some valid values ?

Comment: I would ask Hetzner to connect their remote console system LARA to your server, and diagnose the problem via the console after the boot.